# suggest scrolling select github repos

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm looking for a react select, that is like ios's scrolling select inputs. Like [this one](https://chemzqm.github.io/scroll-select/) which I'm not sure how can I use it in react.

Can you suggest any github repos or links for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely do some google yourself.
but hey I probably found one site you could try:
https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Comment: I'm actively looking for this for couple of days now, and I've also seen regular looking select components. However I'm looking for something that looks like ios's scrolling select inputs. Have you seen something like that?

Comment: Have a look at this one. From what you say I think this meets your requirements: https://github.com/adcentury/react-mobile-picker

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for